# How to match every word in a regex search?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using regex to search for data in my SQL database.

I have columns **Name, Surname, Email, IdNumber**

The idea is the user should be able to search for any value from these columns OR a combination of name and surname, but I can't work out how to split the "Walter White" search string so that it'll match `Name == "Walter"` AND `Surname == "White"`.

Here's my code so far:

```
var pattern = @$"({search})";

var results = new List<Member>();
foreach (var member in context.Members.Where(x => x.IsActive))
{
    // If the currently evaluated item is already in the results, skip.
    if (results.Any(x => x.Id == member.Id)) continue;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(member.Name) && Regex.IsMatch(member.Name, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        results.Add(member);
        continue; // Don't match on any other condition.
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(member.Surname) && Regex.IsMatch(member.Surname, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        results.Add(member);
        continue; // Don't match on any other condition.
    }
    // etc...
}
```

It works if the search query is the email address, id number, name OR surname, but it fails to match if the search query is the name AND surname.

How can I get it to match on name OR surname?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to concat Name and Surname of member instead of trying to split the searchstring?

Comment: @Natrium good shout. I hadn't considered that approach.

Comment: Looks like that works but it's slower than your average politician... 1.8 minutes... Could you post an answer so I can accept